# Why are my hover styles applying to children elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have read what MDN says about the child combinator:

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the children of elements matched by the first. Elements matched by the second selector must be the immediate children of the elements matched by the first selector.

What I don't understand is why the other two `<li>` elements are red, too.

```css
.list > li:hover{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">I should be red</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Why I am red too？</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Why I am red too?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.list > li` you are also including `all` the children of the parent list (which includes the second `ul`)

One way of overriding that is by explicitly setting the properties of the second list:

https://jsfiddle.net/6yeh6ggL/4/:

```
.list li a:hover{
 color:red
}

.list ul li a:hover{
 color:black
}
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining more about "it's the way CSS works". Just saying "that's the way it is" doesn't really educate readers about the subject.

Comment: `It's the way CSS works` what way ? and you completely changed his logic by selecting the a tag, so there is no more issue ... and the second declaration is useless

Comment: Wow! ok, calm down! I was about to edit the answer.....can you give me some minutes? Thanks

Comment: @TemaniAfif "useless" because you say it? Until the author says otherwise you should not assume anything

Comment: @Teknotica Feel free to take all the time you want; I didn't impose a deadline, just commented on an improvement.

Comment: Hey. I am wondering why when I **hover** on the other two li tags and they all turned red too? Is that they inherited the :hover form the first li?

Answer (score 0):

Just to help clarify a little.

Your selector is finding the li item you want which is the first one (it is only finding that one).  The reason all the li's turn red is because color is set to the first li which is inherited by its children and in the case above those li's are its children.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand why when I hover on the immediate children they turned red. But I need to specific my question, why when I **hover** on the other two li tags, they all turned red too? Is that they inherited the ":hover"?

Comment: Yep.  Basically it got your li item and then that item color is set to red.  Since the other li items are inside it they also inherit.  They are basically wrapped by that first li so when you hover on them u are also hovering on that li you selected as well.

Comment: It is not inherited the ":hover", it actually in that block of li. Problem solved!

Comment: I think this is different from inherit.

Comment: No, its inheritied.  When you hover over any of those ul items that is inside of the li item you want red, they are all children of that li.  A better term to use is cascading.  I didnt see the ":hover" at the end of that sentence but it gets inherited then.  But, all that matters is you got it working. :)